# Can't Sort PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Can anybody tell me why I can't get this to work?

I am simply trying to sort my arrays from highest to lowest.

```
$stuff[] = "100";
$stuff[] = "104";
$stuff[] = "102";
$stuff[] = "103";
$stuff[] = "101";
$stuff[] = "99";

echo "Largest: " . max($stuff) . " <br> \n";
arsort($stuff);

echo "0 : " . $stuff[0] . " <br> \n";
echo "1 : " . $stuff[1] . " <br> \n";
echo "2 : " . $stuff[2] . " <br> \n";
echo "3 : " . $stuff[3] . " <br> \n";
echo "4 : " . $stuff[4] . " <br> \n";
echo "5 : " . $stuff[5] . " <br> \n";
```

Comment: How does it not work? What values do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: Hi John,

I get 

Largest: 104
0 : 100
1 : 104
2 : 102
3 : 103
4 : 101
5 : 99

I want sorted highest to lowest.

Comment: `arsort()` maintains index association, so it only makes sense that your output is the same. Try a `foreach` (as suggested [in the manual](http://php.net/arsort)) instead. If you want the highest value to be `$stuff[0]`, use a basic [`rsort()`](http://php.net/rsort)

Answer (score 1):

`arsort()` is sorting your array, but it also conserve the keys of each value. Witch mean the key `0` will still answer with `100`, and not the first element !

With a `foreach`, you would see them in correct order.

```
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br>\n";
}
```

#### OR

You can also use [`rsort()`](http://php.net/rsort) that will not be associative, which mean the keys won't have the same values after it.